# Chrome says: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "<jquery google cdn url>"

Tags: google-chrome, yepnope

In a webapp, I am using `yepnope.js` as a loader (mostly because of its ability to load CSS as well as JS).

However, for whatever gets loaded by **yepnope**, Chrome is giving the warning:

> **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type
>   text/javascript: `<some js file>`**

or

> **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type
>   text/css: `<some css file>`**

This is not creating any problems as far as execution is concerned, but what I don't understand is how is Chrome interpreting a pure JS or CSS file as an IMAGE.

And how to workaround this?

Also, whatever gets loaded from outside of YepNope, is loading perfectly without any warnings.

**PS** :: I don't have any extensions enabled. The only one enabled is **PageSpeed**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sit back and relax, it's just a warning.

yepnope uses `<img>` to pre-load resources. That's why there is a warning.

Read `preloadFile()` in [yepnope.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/yepnope.js).

Answer (score 2):

This is answered by the yepnope team here:
https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/32